# Not able to boot from a new kernel after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I managed to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04, but then when I boot the system, it boots but with the version 12.04 kernel. I checked the /etc/default/grub and /boot/grub2/grub configuration and everything seem okay. But still I cannot boot the new kernel.
I tried to get into boot menu to select the booting kernel but I was not able to get to it. I tried pressing SHIFT and ESC and still the boots with the old kernel. Any help with be very very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First boot with the old kernel. Open a terminal.

Make sure your system is updated by running:

```
sudo su; apt-get update; apt-get upgrade
```

If you are sure you have the newer kernel, run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

To create a new initramfs image.
Now update GRUB with the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

GRUB should have recognized the newer kernel now. Reboot and you should automatically use it. Just to make sure, run `uname -a` to see information about the system and the kernel.