# Don't see new kernel after upgrade

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and want to upgrade to kernel 4.16.9.
Tried: `update-grub`, `update-grub2`, `sudo update-initramfs -u`, `sudo grub2-install /dev/sda`
as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706560/not-able-to-boot-from-a-new-kernel-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04)  and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found) (didn't help).

`uname -a` shows old kernel.
New kernel isn't even in list of additional boot options for Ubuntu in boot menu.

I tried `dpkg -i *.deb` these packages:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I don't think you want to try `4.16.9` but

Go to: [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.9/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.9/)

Select the files:

- linux-headers-4.16.9-041609_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_all.deb
- linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb
- linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb
- linux-modules-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb

for downloading to a directory, say `~/Downloads`.

Then change to the directory, confirm they have finished downloading and install the new kernel:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ ll *.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 10956316 May 16 21:59 linux-headers-4.16.9-041609_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_all.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  1062312 May 16 21:59 linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  7938532 May 16 21:59 linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 45088060 May 16 21:59 linux-modules-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.16.9-041609.
(Reading database ... 603082 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.16.9-041609_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.16.9-041609 (4.16.9-041609.201805161024) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic (4.16.9-041609.201805161024) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic (4.16.9-041609.201805161024) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.16.9-041609-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-4.16.9-041609-generic_4.16.9-041609.201805161024_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.16.9-041609-generic (4.16.9-041609.201805161024) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.16.9-041609 (4.16.9-041609.201805161024) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic:
 linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic depends on linux-base (>= 4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Version of linux-base on system is 4.0ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-modules-4.16.9-041609-generic (4.16.9-041609.201805161024) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.16.9-041609-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-4.16.9-041609-generic
```

Then you'll see an error message because of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-base/+bug/1766851). Now you'll have to fix it using this answer: [Unable to upgrade kernel after 4.16.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030043/unable-to-upgrade-kernel-after-4-16-3)

Comment: So it is not possible to install them because of bug, right ?

Comment: @RS Unless there is a way around the bug. I haven't read the latest reports in a couple of weeks. Maybe someone has a solution.

Comment: Fedora 28 got 4.16.x. Why they were able to use it ?

Comment: @RS Kernel 4.16.1 and 4.16.2 works in Ubuntu just not after that. I don't know what the Red Hat folks are doing with Fedora. I believe that Ubuntu Kernel Team just fumbled the ball with Linux Symbolic Links when they implemented the new modules...deb file but I'm not positive. Anyway it's easy to duplicate the bug by trying to install `4.16.9` as illustrated above.

Comment: Fwiw, I'm on mainline with no issues if you really need to move forward. 18.04 is solid for me on 4.17-rc6 if you're willing to move forward until the more stable 4.16.X branch is fixed.

Comment: 4.17.rc2 also had the symbolic link errors during installation.